Mathematical accuracy of writing the range of a function from max to min?
I teach pre-calculus and find that MOST of my students when writing the range of a function in interval notation will write it from maximum to minimum. For example, one function had a range of $-7\leq y \leq 3$ and many students wrote this as $[3, -7]$. This seems to be a skill that they are carrying over from a previous class. I always instruct them to write their intervals from minimum to maximum, as stating things from least to greatest (left to right) seems to make the most sense. Technically speaking, the interval written as $[3, -7]$ includes the correct values, but that would be similar to writing $3 \geq y \geq -7$, which doesn't seem typical.
So my question is mainly, is it mathematically accurate to write it from greatest to least instead of least to greatest? Is this a battle worth fighting to get them to correct the behavior? Or does it arguably not really matter? I feel like there is some level of importance to learning to write things in a particular order because if they go to take calculus someday, there's a difference between taking an integral from $-7$ up to $3$ vs. taking it from $3$ to $-7$ (though I know this isn't related to range specifically...just similar mindset of the order of things).

Um, no.  "$[3,-7]$" is the set ${y \in \Bbb{R} : 3 \leq y \leq -7}$, which is the empty set.  This is the definition of the "$[a,b]$" notation.

@EricTowers ahh yes, thanks for providing that definition, that makes a lot of sense.

Sometimes it's convenient to define $[a, b]$ as ${x | \min(a, b) \leq x \leq \max(a, b)}$, but this has to be done explicitly. There is nothing wrong with $3 \geq y \geq -7$, though.
